# how do I avoid having to redefine outputs whenever calling a module?

Tags: terraform

I have a module with outputs and that looks like this:

```
output "myvpc" { value = "${aws_vpc.myvpc.id}" }
```

I call that module in another tf file.

Now I want the tf file that calls the module to have those outputs i defined in the module.

But the only way I have been able to do this is to redefine the outputs again in the calling tf file and that looks like this:

```
output "myvpc" { value = "${module.myvpc.myvpc}" }
```

So now I have this redundant line of config and another layer of abstraction for doing something I'd expect would be a pretty necessary thing when using terraform.

Pretty sure I'm doing this wrong because it feels redundant/wrong. The whole purpose of a module is code reuse but having to redefine outputs redundantly and, even worse, mask them with another layer of abstraction like this takes away some of that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is the expected reason, precisely, because modules abstract away the details of implementation.

In writing a module, you are minimizing the contact surface by specifying the variables (parameters) that the model needs, but hiding all implementation details. The same argument applies to the outputs. Instead of all variables being output from the module, you are only exposing the semantically useful values.

If you can accept the above behaviour as valid, then having the same logic apply to the next semantic level seems intuitive as well.

If you need high-level access to values down the chain of abstractions, then you need to write this 'duplicate code'. Note however, that you can rename und change the values according to your semantic needs.